# HighCharts : dynamic data with drill down

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need to generate a interactive chart with drill down functionality. I came across HighCharts, it is very nice and cool, but the data seems to be static. Is there any way to do dynamic data in HighChart and dynamic data for drill down.

```
data = [{
                    y: 55.11,
                    color: colors[0],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: null,
                        categories: null,
                        data: null,
                        color: colors[0]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 21.63,
                    color: colors[1],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Firefox versions',
                        categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
                        data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43],
                        color: colors[1]
                    }
                }];
```

where the value of y is being assigned with static value. I need it to be dynamic and assign a drilldown to each of the value. Can it be done in HighCharts or is there other tools to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that you can use as a starting point:

```
var level = 0;
var refreshChart = function(){  
    new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: getXAxisValues()
        },

        series: [
                    {
                        data: getSeries1()
                    },
                    {
                        data: getSeries2()
                    }
            ],

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            level = 1;
                            refreshChart();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
};

var getSeries1 = function(){
    if(level == 0)
        // returns series data as described in highcharts documentation
    else
        // return some other data
}

// similar to getXAxisValues() if you have it and for getSeries2 if you have another serie
```

Comment: as you can see inside getSeries1, depending on the current level, you generate data, so when level is 1 you generate data fro "detail" level (if that is what you meant by drilldown).

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. But what I need is how can I dynamically assign drilldown to each y value like what you can see in my example, each y value has a [drilldown] tag

Comment: there is no way to do it automatically (as far as I know), so you will have to fetch that drilldown data in "else" part of getSeries1 function.